# CakePHP: HABTM relationship

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have tables: costumers, types and items, as follows:

items belongsTo types
customers HABTM types
customers HABTM items

To check for types ($ this-> Client-> Type-> find ( "all")) must Items are aligned with Types. For example:

- type 1
  -- item A
  -- item B
- type 2
  -- item J
  -- item K

Each type or item should be marked (checkbox) when it is registered to the client. Any idea how to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

To save a HABTM relation you just need send the id of the model that will be related, like this:

```
Array
  (
  [Client] => Array
    (
      [name] => my other Client
      [Item] => Array
        (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 4
      )
    )
  )
```

If you prefer you can check this post that is very clear about how to save HABTM relations http://www.pabloleanomartinet.com/cakephp-2-x-saving-validating-habtm-relation-example/
Thanks